# What are dwarfs in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Lockhart has a bunch of Cupid-like dwarfs:

> Lockhart clapped his hands and through the doors to the
> entrance hall marched a dozen surly-looking dwarfs. Not just any
> dwarfs, however. Lockhart had them all wearing golden wings and
> carrying harps.

Are these dwarfs regular short humans, or some sort of magical creature like house-elves?

Comment: https://www.hp-lexicon.org/creature/sentient/dwarf/ - Short answer (pun intended), we don't know. Apparently they're quite grumpy.

Comment: I think that, unless otherwise specified, we should assume that words in a fictional universe mean the same thing that they do in our own universe.  I see no reason to assume they are somehow special, other than their attire and musical instruments.

Comment: @MishaRosnach, seems unlikely in this case.  Do wizards even suffer from dwarfism?  Surely they couldn't be Muggles?

Comment: ... besides, while *in general* I would agree with your logic, in the fantasy genre mythological dwarfs are far more common than the real-world sort.  In fact, I can't think of any exceptions.  If JKR's dwarfs *are* human, that would perhaps make them unique!

Comment: Good question. This is one of those in-passing things from the early books that are never explained later. Therefore, I would assume they are humans. Wizards do suffer from dwarfism, as seen in Professor Flitwick, however, I think there was something on Pottermore suggesting he might be part goblin. Maybe the cupid dwarves are also part goblins or another smaller sentient creature? Hagrid and Flitwick are clearly considered human, so these dwarves would be as well.

Comment: Also, I was always under the impression that the normal plural was "dwarfs", and "dwarves" was originally Tolkien-specific, then used by other authors and fans to refer to similar fantasy races. Is it possible that the use of  the regular plural "dwarfs" would significantly suggest that these are simply men with dwarfism?

Comment: @HarryJohnston  *"...in the fantasy genre mythological dwarfs are far more common than the real-world sort. In fact, I can't think of any exceptions."*  - I dunno, how about Tyrion Lannister?  I mean, I will agree that Dwarves are a common go-to in Dwarves-and-Elves D&D type stuff, but surely you don't think those define the fantasy genre?

Comment: @MishaRosnach, OK, *one* exception. :-)  And realistically speaking there are probably others, even if I can't think of any right now.  Point is it is rare.  And in this particular case, with elves and goblins and giants and so on all definitely being magical creatures, it seems unlikely that dwarfs are the exception.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Well, one exception off the very top of my head, sure, but also Prof. Flitwick, mentioned in an earlier comment.  Wizard, but not a D&D Dwarf.  And elves in the Harry Potter universe aren't at all like D&D Elves.  There are dragons, but not much in the way of dungeons.  I just don't see any reason to assume that the Harry Potter universe plays by D&D rules (pun proudly intended).

Comment: @MishaRosnach, fantasy dwarfs are hardly restricted to D&D.  [Lots of examples here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurDwarvesAreAllTheSame)   [insert obligatory TVTropes warning] including Narnia, LoTR (of course) and Discworld.  Flitwick isn't a dwarf of either sort, so I don't see that he's relevant.  (I always assumed he was part fairy, but the consensus appears to be goblin.)

Comment: Mostly, though, I just don't think wizards would put up with being made to wear golden wings and carry harps. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I dunno, I suppose I'm not being entirely fair.  If I'm gonna refer to the root of that subdivision of fantasy, I should probably go with Tolkien and not D&D.  However, I think that it's important that we don't just assume a particular trope.  Let the writer pigeonhole herself if she wants, but let's not force it on her.  Also, just purely on ethical grounds - there are real-life dwarfs, and it seems nicer to them to avoid automatically assigning a magical meaning to the word when the fictional universe has humans, and doesn't say anything about dwarfs being inherently mythical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## We can't be sure.

This appears to be one of those loose ends that was never really cleared up. We're not really given any description in the books - they're essentially just described as 'surly'. And they're not ever described - or mentioned again - in the books ever again. So... we can't know.

While searching through Pottermore, though, for some information regarding dwarfs, I found this interesting bit about Red Caps:

> These **dwarf–like creatures** live in holes on old battlegrounds or wherever human blood has been spilled. Although easily repelled by charms and hexes, they are very dangerous to solitary Muggles, whom they will attempt to bludgeon to death on dark nights. Red Caps are most prevalent in northern Europe.
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts & Where to Find Them*, courtesy of [Pottermore](https://web.archive.org/web/20191002072733/https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/what-is-a-red-cap) (emphasis added)</sub>

The Red Caps are described as being 'dwarf-like'. Now, this may be just a coincidence, and it just means short, but it could also be interpreted as being that they're similar to the dwarf species.

Interestingly, the Red Cap looks very similar to a house-elf:

[image: Red Cap]

[image: House Elf]

(and also bear a resemblance to [Goblins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1zax.jpg))

So there's a *slight* possibility that all those small, humanoid, pointy-eared species are related, and that dwarfs are actually a part of that family, given that they all look so similar, and that the Red Caps are described as being dwarf-like.

Comment: I wouldn't put much weight on Atomhawk's illustrations. They're just that artists interpretation of the source texts. All of the interviews with the designers stressed that their goal was to adhere to the source material, and so they aren't a primary source in themselves.

Comment: Also, red caps are part of the unseely court among the sidhe, and are usually reputed to be on the evil side of that line. Bludgeoning travelers would be light for them.

Answer (score 2):

### Rowling has said that there are no "little people" in the Harry Potter universe, so it's probably not that

> **Alfonso Cuarón:** Once I remember having little people in some story boards, playing some keyboards and an organ in the great hall and Jo said "**No, there are not little people in this universe**", and I say "yes but it's like lilliputs kind of" and she says "yes lovely image, but they don't make sense in this universe"
>
> <sub>"Creating the Vision", Prisoner of Azkaban DVD bonus features (2004) [5:10 - 5:30].</sub>

Comment: From my interpretation of this quote, she's referring to truly tiny people, a few inches or shorter, as opposed to creatures a few feet tall.

Comment: @RogueJedi - That's my interpretation as well. We still don't know what these dwarves are, but we at least know they're not tiny people.

Comment: Wow! Great find!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the answer already given which notes that descriptions are very brief, as well as the “surly” description in Chamber of Secrets, they are also mentioned in Prisoner of Azkaban.

In the list of guests at the Leaky Cauldron (on the first page of chapter 4), one of the groups of guests is “raucous dwarfs”. No further description was provided, so this is even thinner than the previous description.